# Facebook Login custom button fail

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I been looking to change the default button for login, I know there are several questions on this but I can't achieve this. I have tried several posts.

This is the code button which works, this is the original btn

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"> <fb:login-button size="large" scope='email,user_birthday'  onlogin="fb_login()"><?php echo $this->get_variable('login');?></fb:login-button></a>
```

This is the way I'm trying to set the button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fb_login();"><img src="images/loginfacebook.png" class="loginfbfb" ></a>
```

and here is the JS code.

```
<script>  

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : <?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>,
          status     : false,
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true
         });
        };

        (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));

        function fb_login() {

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                  if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                    // request, and the time the access token 
                    // and signed request each expire
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    Set_Cookie( '<?php echo COOKIE_FBLOGINSUCCESS;?>', 1, 0 , "/"+'<?php echo $srv_pats;?>','<?php echo $srv_nms;?>') ;
                    
                   // location.href = "<?php echo BASE?>index.php?fb=fb";
                    window.location.reload();
                    
                  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                    // but has not authenticated your app
                  } else {
                    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                  }
                 });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: so what doesn't work? any javascript errors?

Comment: do you have the div with id="fb_root" set up?

Comment: @Reality yes i do, but its <div id="fb-root"></div> with the script provided by Facebook yes....  Not javascript errors, the button just dont work, if im not logged in facebook, im not taken to a login view of facebook, to login in facebook.  With the default button i do.. im redirected to login with facebook.